# Why does my comparator not give an output?

Tags: comparator

I am new to doing electronical things, so I bought some components and I am just trying thing out. 
Now, I am using a LM 2901-comparator, whichs documents you can find [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339-n.pdf).

Using a power supply of 3V, I measured the following pins,

```
Pin 3 (V+): 3.0V
Pin 4 (Input 1-): 1.5V
Pin 5 (Input 1+): 2.2V
Pin 12 (GND): 0.0V
```

according to the documents you would expect pin 2 to be 3.0 V since `Vout = 1 if Vin+ => Vin-`, but it is not giving an output at all.

Anyone that can explain why this is not working?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTUEm3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you mean it's "not giving an output at all"? What is happening? What are you measuring? Is it powered on? Are you sources connected correctly?

Comment: It is giving 0V. I am pretty sure the rest of the pins are wired up correctly. All other pins not mentioned are not connected to anything, could that be a problem?

Comment: Take a 3K - 5K resistor and connect the output to Vcc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An LM339 needs a pull-up resistor on the output or you'll just get diddly-squat ZERO out of it.

[image]

Comment: I've seen the images in the datasheet, but is it ever explicitly written that this resistor is required?

Comment: @sherrellbc yes, page 10 last paragraph

Comment: @sherrellbc Nearly every comparator I remember of this vintage (if not all?) needed a pull-up - I guess it made it more generally suitable to mixed rail supplies. These days there are plenty that are push-pull - I guess the sea of change hapened at some point somewhere!!

Comment: There was probably a use case for tying multiple comparator outputs together in the days before cheap digital processing - e.g. if any single one triggered, sound an alarm, shut off power, etc. The pullup allows this to work.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, perhaps I am taking that statement too literally, but connecting the outputs together would create a short circuit, would it not? The output of an op-amp is just a voltage source with low series resistance.

Comment: Yes; tying multiple *op amp* outputs together would be **bad** for that reason. But this is the likely reason why *comparators* were designed differently, as open collectors needing for a pullup resistor to +V. It is **safe** to tie several comparator outputs together as they cannot pull to different voltages.